# Cannot start Avd with sdkmanager cli (Linux Debian).Error:PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

my sdk-tools folder is in `/root/Downloads` folder and my avd folder is in `/root/.android` folder
Following some StackOverflow question I came to know that the SDK path should be added in `~/.bashrc` .I added

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/root/Downloads/sdk-tools
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
```

, these two lines, now I am getting an error when I run `./emulator -avd pixel`, the name of the avd.

```
Error:PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/root/Downloads/sdk-tools:/root/flutter/bin:/root/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error yesterday all of a sudden.

In my SDKManager I could see a broken image.

I solved the problem by updating the SDK and creating a new AVD.

Comment: Tried that but the same issue.sdkmanager is updated to latest 26.1.1 and i deleted avd folder from /root/.android and create a new avd with same system image i have in sdk-tools folder .now my next step was to modify the path in .bashrc.I did like this:export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/root/Downloads/sdk-tools" where i extracted the sdktool command line interface.Is the path correct why i still get panic message that broken avd system path check android_sdk_root.should i refer the avd folder too in the bashrc the .android folder?.Where am i wrong?